# How to broadcast UDP Packet in Windows Universal App

Tags: c#, windows, sockets, networking, win-universal-app

I am working on a windows universal app. I can send a UDP packet over the network to a particular host using the code i  have. I can see the UDP packet being sent to the particular hostname i specify using Wireshark.

I want to broadcast a message to all the nodes on my network.

Here is what i have, this only sends a packet to particular host which works:

```
   class NetworkInterface
    {
        private DatagramSocket _socket;

        public NetworkInterface()
        {
            _socket = new DatagramSocket();
        }

        public async void Connect(HostName remoteHostName, string remoteServiceNameOrPort)
        {
            await _socket.ConnectAsync(remoteHostName, remoteServiceNameOrPort);
        }

        public async void SendMessage(string message)
        {
            var stream = _socket.OutputStream;

            var writer = new DataWriter(stream);

            writer.WriteString(message);

            await writer.StoreAsync();
        }
    }

    NetworkInterface ni = new NetworkInterface();

    private void ConnectButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Clicked!");
        ni.Connect(new HostName("192.168.120.51"), "5321");
        string cmd = "Hello there\r";

        ni.SendMessage(cmd);
    }
```

This sends a Hello there message to the host.

I am pretty new to Windows universal app and the framework. Also I couldn't find any specific documentation over Web. Please Help.

Comment: _"I couldn't find any specific documentation over Web"_ -- what documentation _did_ you find? Have you researched how to use UDP for broadcast generally? Did you apply those general techniques to your use of `DatagramSocket` specifically? If so, what happened and how was that different from what you wanted to happen? If not, why didn't you? As stated so far, this question in too broad for Stack Overflow; you need to do enough work to get to a point where you have a more specific question than this.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of Connect'ing to a particular Hostname, you should adjust your code to just call GetOutputStreamAsync, pass in the Hostname with the Broadcast address: 255.255.255.255 and then write to the resulting stream. That should let you broadcast your datagram packet over the network.